# How do you represent the pipe symbol in the resource bundle

Tags: java, resourcebundle

How do you represent the "`pipe`" symbol in the resource bundle

e.g. `What is |6|`? The pipe symbol is not getting translated properly for me

Comment: *"The pipe symbol is not getting translated properly for me"* How do you mean *translated*? AFAIK, `|` isn't a special character in resource bundles in general (or in properties file based resources bundles).

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the | is like any other character. A pipe will produce a pipe.

Maybe you're asking about passing a variable using MessageFormat? In which case, you would want something like "What is {6}?" using "{" and "}" as opposed to the "|" character.